# How do I create a list of every combination of 3 digit numbers in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, combinations

I'm trying to write a python script that would output:

000

001

002

...
etc

but I'm running into difficulties.
What I have so far is:

```
from itertools import product


list = [x for x in range(0, 10) if True]
for x in product(list, repeat=3):
    list3 = list(x)


def convert(l):
    c = [str(i) for i in l]
    list2 = int("".join(c))
    return(list2)

print(convert(list3))
```

but this only outputs:

999

I'm not sure how to get the full list.
If I comment out the convert function it provides multiple lists of the numbers, like so:

[0, 0, 0]

[0, 0, 1]

...

Any help would be appreciated, I'm pretty sure I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Why not `print('\n'.join(map(str, range(1,1000))))`? Or `[list(str(x)) for x in range(1,1000)]` if you want a list of the digits.

Comment: you probably will need to work with strings, not numbers. Numbers can't be arranged in "digits" like that

Comment: you are overwriting list3 on every loop, instead of appending to it. Instead of `list3 = list(x)`, do `list3.append(x)`

Comment: That cannot be your actual code.  You have re-used the `list` name, so the call to the `list` function will fail.

Comment: Actually `[list(f'{x:03}') for x in range(1,1000)]` does nicely.

Answer (score 8):

You're overthinking it.

```
for n in range(0, 1000):
    print(f'{n:03}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
import string

for t in itertools.product(string.digits, repeat=3):
    print("".join(t))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use itertools you can also do:

```
from itertools import combinations

lst = [x for x in range(0, 10) if True]
combos = list(combinations(lst, 3))
```

documentation on itertools.combinations is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: You don't need "`if True`"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
from itertools import permutations

digits = [0, 2, 3] #List of digits from which numbers are to be formed
n = 3 #number of digits in a number

num = [int(''.join(map(str, p))) for p in permutations(digits, n) if p[0] != 0]

print(num) #number formed are without repetition of digits
```

If repetition of digits are allowed, then you can try this

```
import itertools
rlist = list(itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3]))
plist = []
for r in rlist:
    num = ''
    for _ in r:
        num += str(_)

    plist.append(int(num))

print(plist)
```